# I am importing Bootstrap in my project but it isn't working

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I want to show cards in the slider. When clicking on the next carousel it will show the next card.

I am importing Bootstrap into my project but it isn't working.

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

I am using this [tutorial](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/alexpiffero-it/696600#html-tab-view) for creating cards and sliders.

You can check the full code [here](https://github.com/Bhavik-Jain/Portfolio)

**Sdata.jsx**

```
const Sdata =[
    {
        imgsrc: work2,
        title: "Android Application",
        href: "https://mybestdjangoblog.herokuapp.com/",
    },
    {
        imgsrc: work3,
        title: "Android Application",
        href: "https://mybestdjangoblog.herokuapp.com/",
    }
   
];
```

**Card.jsx**

```
function Card(props){
    return(
        <>
            <img className="card-img-top"
                src={props.imgsrc} alt="" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-title">{props.title}</h4>
                <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.</p>
                <a href={props.href} className="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">View Project</a>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

**Work.jsx**

```
const Work =() =>{
    return(
      <>
        <div id="multi-item-example" className="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">
          <div className="controls-top">
            <a className="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="prev"><i className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a className="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="next"><i
                className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>

          <ol className="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          
          <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div className="carousel-item active">
              <div className="col-md-3" style={{ float: "left"}}>
                <div className="card mb-2">
                  <img className="card-img-top"
                  src={work1} alt="" />
                  <div className="card-body">
                  <h4 className="card-title">Android Application</h4>
                  <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                      card's content.</p>
                  <a href="https://mybestdjangoblog.herokuapp.com/" className="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">View Project</a>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-3" style={{float:"left"}}>
                    <div className="card mb-2">
                      {Sdata.map((val, ind) => {
                          return(
                            <Card key={ind} imgsrc={val.imgsrc} title={val.title} href={val.href}/>
                          )})}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>         
      </>
```

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You should install `bootstrap` as:

1. `npm i react-bootstrap`
2. `npm i bootstrap`

Then import styles as:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

[image: Edit gifted-bas-v5qzp]

Comment: @BhavikJain was this approach acceptable and solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install`

will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json.